Retrofit OkHttp with Moshi: Gzip Encoding Error
I'm using Retrofit with OkHttp and Moshi. I have to add the "Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate, br" header myself. But OkHttp adds its own "Accept-Encoding" header.
Due to this situation, the following error occurs:
com.squareup.moshi.JsonDataException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at path $

If I remove the "Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate, br" header from the interceptor, it works fine. But I shouldn't remove it.
Here is my code:
class CustomInterceptor : Interceptor {
    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response = chain.run {
        proceed(
            request()
                .newBuilder()
                .addHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br")
                .build()
        )
    }
}

OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .addInterceptor(CustomInterceptor())
    .build()

Moshi.Builder()
    .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
    .build()

Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("myurl")
    .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi).asLenient())
    .client(okHttpClient)
    .build()

How can I solve this?

"But I shouldn't remove it" -- why? Your OkHttp setup does not support Brotli (br) compression, because you have not added the Brotli interceptor. It is unclear to me if OkHttp supports deflate. Why do you feel that overriding what OkHttp advertises in Accept-Encoding is necessary?

Request works fine with "deflate, br" header. Problem is "gzip". OkHttp does gzip decompression automatically. But my header must include "gzip".

Try to add ScalarsConverterFactory to Retrofit, something like this: Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("myurl").addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi).asLenient()).addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create()).client(okHttpClient).build()        .

Not worked with ScalarsConverterFactory too. @A.Cedano
